# Filtering Python Objects

Tags: python

I am trying to extend the following 'get_people' Python function.

```
def get_people(profession, cities):
    all_people = _load_people() # loads all_people from in-mem cache.
    data = []
    for people in all_people:
        if people.profession is profession and people.address.city in cities:
        data.append(people)

    return data
     
class People:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, profession, address):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last 
        self.age = age
        self.profression = profession
        self.address = address
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.first + " " + self.last + " " + str(self.age) 
    
class Address:
    def __init__(self, city, street, zipcode):
        self.city = city
        self.street = street
        self.zipcode = zipcode
```

Now get_people() python function has to support advance queries, for ex:

1. return all people living in Newyork City and their Profession is either a lawyer or an engineer.
2. return all people living in (Newyork city or Seattle City) or their profession is a lawyer
3. return all people living in (Newyork city or Seattle City) and their profession is a lawyer
4. return all people living in Newyork city and Age > 40
5. return all people with the profession as accountant or age > 30
6. many more combinations like this...

How can I take such filtering input in the get_people() function? I was thinking to design PersonFilter class and take PersonFilter class as an input to get_person function.

Any lead in designing PersonFilter class is highly appreciated.

Comment: Accept a filter function as input to `get_people`. Apply it to all the value & return the remaining.

Comment: Don't use `is` when you really mean `==`.

Answer (score 0):

The easier and flexible way to do this is pass a `filter` as `get_people` function argument. This function will receive a `People` object:

```
def get_people(filter):
    all_people = _load_people() # loads all_people from in-mem cache.
    data = []
    for people in all_people:
        if filter(people):
            data.append(people)

    return data
```

In your first query, for example:

> return all people living in Newyork City and their Profession is
> either a lawyer or an engineer.

you can make something like this:

```
people = get_people(lambda people: people.addres.city == 'New York'
                    and people.profession in ['lawyer', 'engenier'])
```